# Assign value to textbox onchange of php while select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm slowly understanding PHP but this one has me stumped.
I am populating a 'select' HTML element with data from PHP using.....
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    All is working fine and I understand why.
I just wanted to fill in other textboxes on the page when a selection is made.
There is a very helpful fiddle at  http://jsfiddle.net/TPE9r/5/  but it does not use PHP.
This is part of my code...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<option value=" ',$row['ContactID'],' ">', $row['ContactName'],' -- ',    $row['BusinessName'],
'</option>';}
```

Sorry about the formatting - new on here also...
I have used similar JavaScript to the fiddle but I can't display $row['ContactName'] or $row['BusinessName'] in a textbox.            I can do this with a normal HTML select but not when the rows are in a 'while loop'

Comment: on change of Select , what value u want to display in txtbox?

Comment: In answer to  jQuery Angry Bird ..... When a selection is made I want to put the value of $row['BusinessName'] in the textbox

Comment: Just wanted to add a bit more......I have played around with hidden texboxes, cookies and using jquery 'this' and a couple of other approaches. None was easy to understand or use although I got the feeling that "jquery 'this'" was going to be the best approach.

Comment: Although I haven't tested it yet, it looks like the solution from 'lolka_bolka' below might be the best.  I'm still digging around as I'm convinced I should be able to grab data from inside the while loop onselect!  I've just spent an hour or 2 playing with data-attributes. Found another helpful fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/X4JvA/1/ but again each option is coded - I need to adapt this to dynamic

Answer (score 0):

because you try to do something, what should be done on other way.

In the `while` loop, you are putting out the `options` html tags.

To do this, i think, the best practice, if you build an array from your results, so you can use that later, if you want to do it in PHP.

The code is not tested.

```
echo '<select name="whatever">';
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //Storing all the rows in an array
    $results[] = $row;
}
for($i=0;$i < count($results); $i++) {
    echo '<option value=" ',$results[$i]['ContactID'],' ">', $results[$i]['ContactName'],' -- ',    $results[$i]['BusinessName']."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
//And now you can youse your $resuls array more then one time.
$key = 0;
//The key is based on, wich data you need.
//Maybe you want to set it in the loop with an if condition
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$results[$key]['ContactName'],' -- ',    $results[$key]['BusinessName'].'" />';
```

Comment: Thanks 'lolka_bolka' for this and it may be the best approach.  I kind of get the feeling that when the choice is displayed in the select I should have access to other fields in the row at that exact time and should be able to put these fields in textboxes. This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XfPv7/1/  is close but I can't adapt it

Comment: This is why I sad, you can set the `$key` variable there. For example, if your desired row is the 3rd element in your array, then set `$key = 2;` (arrays started from 0); You just need to put there an if condition, if i undestand you. You can not add `<input...` elements inside a `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solved this one - maybe not the best way but it may help others.
I used  :  `$(this).find(':selected').data('id')` ....  in the `onchange`
and used `data-attributes` in the loop

```
for($i=0;$i < count($results); $i++) {
echo '<option data-id="'.$results[$i]['ContactID'],' " data-bn="'.$results[$i]['BusinessName'],' " >'. $results[$i]['ContactName']. 

"</option>";
```

and 3 textboxes whose id is  bb, cc, dd ....

```
price2= this.value;
price1 = $(this).find(':selected').data('id')
price3 = $(this).find(':selected').data('bn')

$('#bb').val(price1);
$('#cc').val(price2);
$('#dd').val(price3);
```

Just a bit tricky with single and double quotes in the loop but 'Hey that's what we do!'

Answer (score 0):

Trying to post my own answer - having trouble with formatting on here.

The loop should be

for($i=0;$i < count($results); $i++) {
echo ''. $results[$i]['ContactName'].

"";

OOPS!!!!! Done it again - the loop code is truncated - don't know why

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead. You do not want the value of the option but the text.

```
$('#job_title').live('change', function(){    
    var b = $(this).text();           
    $('#catch_value').val(b);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: live() function is deprecated as of Jquery 1.7. Use on(). instead. Also downvoted as the code you gave is just a rehash of the code he pointed out in his original question, He already knew about this code